# Is It Possible To Use Reflection To Pass A COM Object From C# to C++?

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop

I have a C# assembly that does some work and sends the results of the work back to a C++ core. I am trying to use Reflection to pass it back since the C# assembly runs on a different thread than the one it was initialized by from the C++ core. I have tried using the COM interface as the parameter type.

IDL:

```
    HRESULT SendEvent([in] IEventData *pEventData);
```

C#:

```
    WECOInspectionCoreIDL.IEventData eventData = new EventData() as WECOInspectionCoreIDL.IEventData;
    var parameters = new object[1];
    parameters[0] = eventData;
    _piInspectionCore.GetType().InvokeMember("SendEvent", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, _piInspectionCore, parameters);
```

This gets the error "0x80020005 Type mismatch" in the atlcom.h hRes = m_pInfo->Invoke(...) call which apparently eventually gets converted to "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' ... No such interface supported.

I've also tried making the parameter an IDispatch* and then the call goes through to C++, but it doesn't seem to be the real object.

IDL:

```
    HRESULT SendEvent([in] IDispatch *pEventData);
```

C++:

```
    STDMETHODIMP CInspectionCore::SendEvent(IDispatch *pEventData)
    {
       IEventData *pIEventData = (IEventData *)pEventData;
```

Even calling pIEventData->GetIDsOfNames() fails.

Is there a way to pass a COM object created in C# to C++ when the C# object is called from a different C++ thread?

Comment: From a high level point of view, the second method should work. Please provide a full reproducing simple sample so we can investigate more.

Comment: I've made an example that I think reproduces the problem. I'm not sure what the acceptable way to make the ZIP available is.

Comment: I've attempted to make a GitHub project: https://github.com/wecobill/CallCppFromCSharpWithCOMParameter

Comment: The solution doesn't compile easily. C# and C++ projects are both referencing themselves. You should define all COM interfaces one unique .tlb (possibly in the C++ project since you already have an idl there). Then reference that from C#. Do that, update your github project, and let's retry.

Comment: I'm not completely happy with the organization (interfaces are duplicated in Core.idl and COM.idl), but I got the files out of GItHub and was able to build them and reproduce the problem in CDoWork::SendEvent().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With COM, you should **never** cast a COM interface into another COM interface like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP CInspectionCore::SendEvent(IDispatch *pEventData)
{
    IEventData *pIEventData = (IEventData *)pEventData; // wrong!
}
```

Instead you **must** use [QueryInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)), this works fine:

```
STDMETHODIMP CInspectionCore::SendEvent(IDispatch *pEventData)
{
    IEventData* pIEventData;
    HRESULT hr = pEventData->QueryInterface(&pIEventData);
    if (FAILED(hr)) // etc.
}
```

In some cases (in fact often), raw casting may work which can give the false impression that it's ok.

In your case, it doesn't work because you use different threads which creates implicit proxies ([COM apartments, etc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/processes--threads--and-apartments)). You can see that if you breakpoint in `SendEvent` have a look at the call stack when it's called, it's all COM marshaling stuff.